# Building a javascript client for the TFS SOAP webservice

Tags: javascript, soap, tfs, authorization, fiddler

I am trying to build a javascript client that gets information about active projects on a TFS.

Since TFS has SOAP endpoints I was thinking of using wsdl2js ( http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tools.html ) to generate a local proxy and then call the functions that i need on that proxy (like list projects, etc).

Here's my js code:

```
    function showresponse(response)
    {
        alert("rasp");
    }

    function showerror(error)
    {
        alert('error');
    }


    var test=new ClassificationSoap();
    test.url="http://192.168.48.130:8080/Services/v1.0/CommonStructureService.asmx";
    test.ListAllProjects(showresponse,showerror);
```

However, neither of the response functions are called.

According to CommonStructureService.asmx here's how the request should look:

```
POST /Services/v1.0/CommonStructureService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.48.130
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Classification/03/ListAllProjects"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ListAllProjects xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Classification/03" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I fired fiddler, and here's how my raw request looks:

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.48.130:8080/Services/v1.0/CommonStructureService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.48.130:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30
Access-Control-Request-Headers: MessageType, SOAPAction, Content-Type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

As you can see, there is no xml sent.

Here's the raw response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1656
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 17:14:08 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>You are not authorized to view this page</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<STYLE type="text/css">
  BODY { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }
  H1 { font: 13pt/15pt verdana }
  H2 { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }
  A:link { color: red }
  A:visited { color: maroon }
</STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY><TABLE width=500 border=0 cellspacing=10><TR><TD>

<h1>You are not authorized to view this page</h1>
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.
<hr>
<p>Please try the following:</p>
<ul>
<li>Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page.</li>
<li>Click the <a href="javascript:location.reload()">Refresh</a> button to try again with different credentials.</li>
</ul>
<h2>HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration.<br>Internet Information Services (IIS)</h2>
<hr>
<p>Technical Information (for support personnel)</p>
<ul>
<li>Go to <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=8180">Microsoft Product Support Services</a> and perform a title search for the words <b>HTTP</b> and <b>401</b>.</li>
<li>Open <b>IIS Help</b>, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr),
 and search for topics titled <b>About Security</b>, <b>Authentication</b>, and <b>About Custom Error Messages</b>.</li>
</ul>

</TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

So basically it says it needs authentication.

Why isn't the showerror function called? How can my client know how to ask user for credentials?

Also, how does authentication work?

I know I need to send an authorization header that contains "user:pass" encoded with base64, but I can't find any reference to this in the generated Classification.js

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a javascript client built? Is that something you can share?

Comment: No I haven't. I used a different approach where I created a WCF REST webservice and used the tfs api to authenticate the user on the tfs server. Afterwords the service returned jsons with requested info (projects, user stories, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note that your first request was an OPTIONS request, not a POST. Are you sending your request to a cross-origin server using XMLHTTPRequest?  If so, the server needs to be configured, via CORS, to return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin directive in response to that pre-flight OPTIONS request.